# How to uninstall rubymine from UBUNTU

Tags: ruby

I was trying to upgrade from RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1 to 6 for that I was trying to uninstall RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1. I removed RubyMine directory from where I installed RubyMine. Now everytime I need to run RubyMine version 6 from the .sh file given in RubyMine 6. How to completely remove the RubyMine and do a fresh installation.
FYI.. There is no such file or folder called ~/Library to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just try this:

```
locate rubymine
```

you will get the path of of desktop launcher then just remove it

```
rm {{PATH}}
```

you need to root user to remove this launcher

Answer (score 3):

RubyMine installation consists of the following:

- Application directory where you have unpacked RubyMine
- [system/config/plugins directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)
- optional command line launcher script (like `/usr/bin/mine`)
- optional desktop shortcut

It's recommended to install and start RubyMine 6 first so that it can import your old version settings, then you can remove all the items mentioned above for the previous version.

Use the Tools menu or the corresponding welcome screen items to create the new command line launcher and desktop shortcut if needed.

Comment: I tried but there is no launcher script at /usr/bin/mine.

Comment: You specify the location for the launcher script when you create it, so it may be different on your system.

Comment: @SatyamSingh Maybe it's late. But it could be `/usr/local/bin/mine`